# What is the probability that exactly 3 one hundred dollar bills are chosen?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

**STATEMENT** At a casino, one lucky player is blindfolded and allowed to pick $5$ bills from a bowl containing $25$ bills. The bowl contains $6$ one hundred dollar bills, $3$ fifty dollar bills, and the rest of the bills of various other denominations.

**QUESTION:**

**a.** What is the probability that exactly 3 one hundred dollar bills are chosen?

**b.** Find the variance for the number of one hundred dollar bills that can be chosen?

**MY WORKING:**

Let $X$ denote the number of one hundred dollar bills chosen by blindfolded player then $X$ is binomial random variable with $p$ denoting the probability of success (which is to chose one hundred dollar bill), with $p=\frac{6}{25}=0.24$. Then:

**a.** By using binomial distribution we have: $P(X=3)={25 \choose 3}(0.24)^3(0.76)^{25-3}=2300\times0.013824\times0.002387=0.075$

**b.** since $Var(X)=np(1-p)=25\times0.24\times0.76=4.56$

I am preparing for my upcoming exams by solving past papers. I don't have the key to the questions. I need surety if my calculations are correct. Guidance will be appreciated, in case there is a mistake. Thanks

Comment: These calculations are incorrect.  Here, it is clear that *exactly* $5$ bills are to be chosen, so we can not assume independence.  As the numbers involved are all very small, there is no reason to approximate so just work it out exactly.

Comment: Will it require conditional probability? i.e: Given that $5$ bills are chosen we have to calculate the probability that $3$ among them will be one hundred dollar bills.

Comment: Hypergeometric distribution

Comment: Don't guess.  There are $\binom {25}5$ equally probable ways to choose $5$ bills. There are $\binom {19}5$ ways to choose $5$ non-hundreds.  Thus the probability of choosing $0$ hundreds is the ratiio $\binom {19}5\big/\binom {25}5\approx .219$  And so on.

Comment: Usage of binomial distribution is incorrect, because after choosing first bill whatever denomination it has, probability of choosing one hundred bill changes.

Comment: @Ameer786 Does the answer help? If yes, mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the binomial distribution, you have considered the case *with replacement* i.e. after you choose a bill, you put it back, so there are still 25 options.

The question seems like it wants the case *without replacement*, however. To pick three \$100 bills out of five, you need 3 bills from the pile of 6 \$100 bills and 2 bills from the pile of 19 not-\$100 bills. The number of ways to choose this, where the order matters, is:

$$ 6\times5\times4\times19\times18 $$

But the order doesn't matter, so we divide through by symmetries to get:

$$ \frac{6\times5\times4\times19\times18}{3\times 2\times 1\times 2\times 1}=5\times2\times19\times18 $$

And how many total ways are there to choose $5$ bills out of $25$, dividing by symmetries?

$$ \frac{25\times 24\times 23\times 22\times 21}{5\times 4\times 3\times 2\times 1} $$

So the probability is the ratio of the two:

$$ \frac{5\times2\times19\times18\times5\times 4\times 3\times 2\times 1}{25\times 24\times 23\times 22\times 21} = \frac{19\times6}{23\times11\times7}=\frac{114}{1771} $$

If you know the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution), you could skip this derivation of its pmf from first principles and jump straight to: $$\frac{{6\choose 3}\times{19\choose 2}}{25\choose 5}$$

To find the variance, you could have learned a formula for the variance of a hypergeometric distribution. If not, maybe you know that $\text{Var}(X)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-\mathbb{E}(X)^2$. The possible values of $X$ here are $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and generalising the above calculation (for $X=2$) tells you how to calculate the probability that $X$ takes each value.

Comment: It helped alot sir. Thank you